# modal codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Tengo este código pero no me abre la modal , estoy trabajando con `MATERIALIZE` , no con `BOOSTRAP`

```js
var ID_AGENTE;
jQuery.ready(function($) {
   
    $('.btn-eliminar').click(function(e){
      
      e.preventDefault();
      
      Id_Producto = $(this).attr('href');
     
      $('#modalBox').modal('show');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
   <a href="#" class='btn btn-danger btn-eliminar'><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
</td>                  
<button id="modalBox" type="button" style="display: none;" class="btn btn-default waves-effect m-r-20" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal">MODAL - LARGE SIZE</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="largeModalLabel">Auto a Editar</h4>
        </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar Ventana</button>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jaziel , con qué elemento desea abrir su ventana modal ? con `.btn-eliminar` ? , probó quitando el parámetro  `'open'` y dejar solo `$('#modalBox').modal();` además de modificar el ready en su Javascript ? 
`$(document).ready(function() { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Algunas consideraciones a tener en cuenta y posiblemente influyan para que no se muestre la ventana modal

El método [ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) del Inicio de su Javascript , cambiar por `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` o de forma corta `$(function() { ...});` ya que como se muestra parece ser incorrecto.

Añadir el atributo `data-target` que apunte al Id de tu modal  `data-target="#largeModal"`

Llamar al método `modal('open');` pero sin parámetros  de la siguiente forma `$('#largeModal').modal();`

No olvidar agregar las clases `modal-action modal-close` al `boton` para poder cerrar la ventana Modal

```js
$(function() {
 $('.btn-eliminar').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#largeModal').modal();
   });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.js"></script>
<td>
   <a href="#largeModal" class='btn btn-danger btn-eliminar'><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
</td>                  
<button id="modalBox" type="button" style="display: none;" class="btn btn-default waves-effect m-r-20" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal">MODAL - LARGE SIZE</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="largeModalLabel">Auto a Editar</h4>
        </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link modal-action modal-close waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar Ventana</button>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```